# How to draw direct to raspberrypi screen with golang

Tags: go, raspberry-pi

I search a best practice to draw( ellipse, circle, png image etc... with mask combination) direct to a raspberypi Screen and in fullscreen without windows borders,etc....

I've found many document which explian image/draw package but i've not found code example or boilerplate to start my project With GO.

My project is to draw a "robot face" on Pi screen will react to camera mouvements. Currently i draw it in python with pygame like this :

```
pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

but i want to migrate to GO.

Any help will be welcome to give me the right way to do or code examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using pygame before then [pixel](https://github.com/faiface/pixel) might be what you are looking for. It's a simple to use and has some great examples listed in the github README.

Comment: hi,  thanks i've tried it but, it need X11 server to draw to screen, to direct pass through GPU